# How to run in debug for command line arguments

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I want to debug this code, that is setup to run off a SQL SERVER agent job with a passed param. I want to have it run for '5' here but how can I do this if its setup for passed param?

```
if (arrProgType != null && arrProgType.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrProgType.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "1")
        {
            Order.RunOrder();
        }
        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "2")
        {
            Shipment.RunShipment();
        }
        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "3")
        {
            Acknowledgments.RunAcknowledgments();
        }
        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "4")
        {
            Invoices.RunInvoices();
        }
        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "5")
        {
            ReportFtpVersion.RunGetReports();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the Project Properties window, you can add commandline arguments from the Debug section.

Comment: i see. is it 'user control?

Comment: Just click on debug on the left hand side, then you'll see Start Options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

(1) - select project, hit Alt+Enter (Opens Project Properties)

(2) - Debug Tab

(3) - Provide Parameters

Answer (score 2):

Right click you **project** go to **Properties** and then go to **Debug** section and find **Command Line Arguments** text area and there you can provide arguments for debugging or testing your application:

[image]